# AWS ECS Fargate - django runserver will be billed 24/7?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a django app in a dockerfile, and I deployed it with ECS Fargate. It works well, but I'm am not sure about how pricing works.

`python manage.py runserver` has to be running all the time because it needs to be listening the incoming requests. Does it mean that my fargate is beign used 24/7. and subsequently billed 24/7?. If that is true, what is the correct way to use a monolithic app in a fargate container minimizing costs?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' ./local/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./local/entrypoint.sh

RUN pip install -r ./local/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "./local/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

echo "------- RUNNING DJANGO COMMANDS -------"
python /app/manage.py makemigrations
python /app/manage.py migrate
python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fargate instance runs 24/7 and is billed 24/7. Don't be confused with Fargate being called "serverless". Just because you don't manage the underlying server, you are still reserving some AWS hardware (via the Fargate CPU and Memory reservation settings) 24/7, so you pay for those underlying resources 24/7. Fargate is not AWS Lmabda. Fargate runs all the time.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, running your Django Application on AWS ECS Fargate means that your application is running 24/7.
Therefore you'll be billed for that amount of time.

There are a few things you can do in order to minimize the costs in AWS ECS Fargate itself:

1. Scale with Demand: If you expect the demand    for your application
   to be variable, consider setting up Auto    Scaling for ECS
   services. This allows you to automatically adjust    the desired
   count of tasks in your service up and down within    minimum and
   maximum count values.
2. Optimize Resources: Select the right task size. When defining a task
   for Fargate, you specify the amount of vCPU and memory it needs.
   Make sure you choose a configuration that best fits the needs of
   your application without over-provisioning.
3. Use Spot Capacity: Starting from late 2019, Fargate started
   supporting spot pricing, which can give you up to 70% cost savings
   over On-Demand prices. These are spare capacity and can be
   interrupted, but for stateless or fault-tolerant applications, they
   are a good choice.

Now, if I may give you a tip; don't use `python manage.py runserver` in production. The `runserver` command is built for local development, you rather look at something like `gunicorn` for production.

Comment: You are totally right about using runserver. I'll fix that in my next commit jeje. I found this Medium post with a django architecture https://betterprogramming.pub/design-an-auto-scalable-architecture-for-your-django-apps-in-aws-850ca5ec63a1 thanks a lot